# Pulling data from GA4 to AWS Jupyter Notebook

Tags: google-analytics-api, amazon-sagemaker, google-analytics-4

I am trying to pull data from GA4 into my AWS Jupyter notebook for long term storage. I want to hit all dimensions/metrics but google analytics limits queries to 10 metrics and 7 dimensions. Only solution I could think of was to use a for loop, surely there is a better way than the code I've done below?

```
# Authenticate with Google Analytics API

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('Path-To-Key')
client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient(credentials=credentials)

# Replace with the path to your JSON credentials file

KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'Path-To-Key'

# Replace with the Analytics Admin API version you want to use

API_VERSION = 'v1alpha'

# Replace with the Analytics Admin API scope(s) you want to use

SCOPES = \['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'\]

# Create credentials from the JSON file

credentials_2 = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, scopes=SCOPES)

# Create an instance of the Analytics Admin API client

analytics_admin = build('analyticsadmin', API_VERSION, credentials=credentials_2)

# Call the accounts().list() method to retrieve a list of accounts

accounts = analytics_admin.accounts().list().execute()

# Accumulator for all property IDs

all_property_ids = \[\]

# Function to extract property id from properties

def extract_property_ids(data):
property_ids = \[\]
for item in data:
property_name = item\['name'\]
property_number = property_name.split('/')\[1\]
property_id = f"properties/{property_number}"
property_ids.append(property_id)
return property_ids

# Loop through each account and retrieve its properties/property ids

for account in accounts.get('accounts', \[\]):
properties = analytics_admin.properties().list(filter=f"parent:{account\['name'\]}").execute()
property_ids = extract_property_ids(properties.get('properties', \[\]))
all_property_ids.extend(property_ids)

# Define the date range and dimensions/metrics to retrieve

date_range = DateRange(start_date='7daysAgo', end_date='today')
dimensions = \[Dimension(name='country')\]
metrics = \[Metric(name='screenPageViews')\]

for property_id in all_property_ids:

    request = RunReportRequest(
        property=property_id,
        dimensions=dimensions,
        metrics=metrics,
        date_ranges=[date_range],
    )
    
    response = client.run_report(request)
    
    # Convert the response object to a dictionary
    data_dict = MessageToDict(response._pb)
    
    # Convert the dictionary to a JSON string
    data_json = json.dumps(data_dict)
    
    # Save the data to a file on the local disk with name being property id associated with it
    filename = f'GA4 Test Data/Data_{property_id}.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data_json)
```

Comment: The API is for giving you a report. Not the whole data. Maybe you need to connect the GA4 with BigQuery and try to pull data from bigQuery out as json file. But it is the raw data. Not sure it will be what you want.